# pushGLStates returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION when used

Tags: c++, opengl, user-interface, sfml

im trying to make a gui for my game using SFML so have been advised to use glpush and pop states. and enter my commands to draw the gui in between the push and pop. So this is what i have :

```
void Engine::run()
{
while (App.isOpen())
{
    while (c_FPSClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() < 1.f/60)
    {
    }




    // Set the active window before using OpenGL commands
    // It's useless here because active window is always the same,
    // but don't forget it if you use multiple windows or controls
    App.setActive();



    App.pushGLStates();
    App.draw(text);
    App.popGLStates();

    // Clear color and depth buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();



    getInput();
    update();
    render();

    App.display();
}
}
```

But this is making my game mess up pretty bad:

```
- The input isn't working like before at all
- The player is rendering below the map
```

all i want to do is draw some text to display health and a rectangle at the bottom of the screen! haha.

I am also getting these errors in the console

> An internal OpenGL call failed in RenderTarget.cpp <255> : GL_INVALID_OPERATION,the specified operation is not allowed in the current state

The game is built with C++ OpenGL and SFML to render the window and gui

Comment: how do you declare `sf::RenderWindow`?

Comment: I think you have to be more specific on what your functions getInput(), update() and render() actually do. Make sure that you always put all sfml render calls such as `App.draw` between   `App.pushGLStates()` and `App.popGLStates()`